# SharePoint list modifying the existed item while retrieve and populate values from list A (using item id) to list B to create a new item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-list

I have two SharePoint lists: list A & list B.

For example

```
 list A fields: text 1, text 2, Button     
 list B fields: Name, text 1, text 2
```

Workflow(2010) will generate a hyperlink in list A button field for each item added to list A, upon clicking on button it will redirect to list B with auto populated fields text 1, text 2 from list A (here used list A Item ID in URL) and user will enter Name & click save.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Once saved workflow (2010) will send a notification. able to do the retrieval using JavaScript which was working fine, after recreating the workflow to 2013 while testing it, able to retrieve the values from list A to list B but it is modifying existed item in list B with same ID instead creating new item, and sometimes giving page not found error after loading few seconds.

For example list A item ID 100 which will be passed  to list B `newform.aspx?ID=100` (workflow generated URL in list A) while retrieving the values from list A and populate in list B `newform.aspx`. Once clicked on Save, it is modifying list B item with ID 100 which is already there in list B. this supposed create a new item with unique ID.

Trying to  find out where I was doing wrong.

Please help, let me know if need more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say where goes wrong without any information about how you create the new workflow. If you can provide the structure of your new 2013 workflow, we may be able to provide some help.

And as you are using SharePoint Online, I will suggest you to use MS Power Automate (Also called as Flow) instead of using 2013 workflow. It is more integrated with other applications and much easier to use.